# Copy-Pasteable Text in pygtk's TreeView

Tags: gtk, pygtk, gtktreeview

I came across this rather unexpected problem. I have a gtk.TreeView with a single text column, that is rendered by gtk.CellRendererText. What I want is that the user can mark the displayed text using the mouse and get it into the clipboard by pressing ctrl+c. (I am referring to the very basic feature present in every webbrowser and texteditor). However, gtk won't let me do it. I have a simple example here, with non-markable / non-highlightable text:

```
import gtk

class TreeViewExample(gtk.TreeView):

    def __init__(self):
        gtk.TreeView.__init__(self)
        self.get_selection().set_mode(gtk.SELECTION_NONE)
        self.set_grid_lines(gtk.TREE_VIEW_GRID_LINES_HORIZONTAL)

        # create  model
        self.list_store = gtk.ListStore(str)
        self.list_store.append(['Hello, this is some \n multiline text.'])
        self.list_store.append(['Another text.'])
        self.set_model(self.list_store)

        # create text column
        col = gtk.TreeViewColumn('Text Column')
        self.append_column(col)
        cell = gtk.CellRendererText()
        col.pack_start(cell, True)
        col.add_attribute(cell, 'text', 0)



class MasterWindow(object):

    def destroy(self, widget, data=None):
        gtk.main_quit()

    def __init__(self):
        self.window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
        self.window.set_size_request(500,500)
        self.window.connect("destroy", self.destroy)       
        self.window.add(TreeViewExample())
        self.window.show_all()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    mw = MasterWindow()
    gtk.main()
```

I could of course make the cell editable, because the editable mode provides the feature. But that is far from elegant, because it is some kind of popup, that breaks the line wrap and, well, edits the text. What i need is a cell, that is not selectable, editable or anything, but has text, that can be copied.

Does anyone have a solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I made some changes in the code.
Try the code below, this example works well and I am sure that is the answer to your question.
Hope this helps you in the future of their knowledge and coding.

```
import gtk

class TreeViewExample():
    def __init__(self):        
        self.window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
        self.window.set_size_request(500,500)       

        model = gtk.ListStore(str)
        model.append(['a'])
        model.append(['b'])
        model.append(['c'])

        treeview = gtk.TreeView(model)

        self.renderer = gtk.CellRendererText()
        self.renderer.set_property('editable', True)
        treeview.insert_column_with_attributes(-1, 'Copy-Pastable-Editable String', self.renderer, text=0)

        self.window.add(treeview)
        self.window.show_all()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    TreeViewExample()
    gtk.main()
```

Comment: Basically, your solution is to make the cell editable, but not provide a callback to stop changes from being saved.

Comment: You are right in this coment, but @Pappenheimer only want make editable,copy & pastable his cells. If you want save changes in some cell have update you listore.

Comment: It's still not ideal, because the user can seemingly change the contents of the cell, only to have the changes revert upon losing focus.

Comment: In my opinion it's transparent to the user. The data on a TreeView built in a listore, if not change the data in the model the treeview can't show the data that you want ,because not exist in the model list that became to listore

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes in the code. Trying to answer questions of **@Flimm**.I hpe Helps you  **@Flimm**.

```
import gtk

class TreeViewExample():
    def __init__(self):        
        self.window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
        self.window.set_size_request(500,500)       

        self.model = gtk.ListStore(str,str)
        self.model.append(['a','b'])
        self.model.append(['c','a'])
        self.model.append(['d','a'])
        self.model.append(['e','a'])            
        self.treeview = gtk.TreeView(self.model)

        self.renderer = gtk.CellRendererText()
        self.renderer.set_property('editable', True)
        self.renderer.connect('edited', self._text_changed, 0)
        self.treeview.insert_column_with_attributes(-1, 'Copy-Pastable-Editable String', self.renderer, text=0)
        self.treeview.insert_column_with_attributes(-1, 'Copy-Pastable-Editable String', self.renderer, text=1)            

        self.window.add(self.treeview)
        self.window.show_all()

    def _text_changed( self, w, row, new_value, column):
        self.model[row][column] = new_value
if __name__ == '__main__':
    TreeViewExample()
    gtk.main()
```

Comment: I realise you can add a callback to edit the list store to make the changes permanent. That's not what I meant. What I meant is that it would be good if one could select the text, but type "a", "b", or any random letters, and *those letters would not appear even temporarily*.